# upgrade from lucid to precise

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

I am running lucid, and would like to upgrade to precise. I have changed the settings in Update Manager to "Long term support releases only", but I only get the option "New Ubuntu release '10.10' is available". I thought it was possible to upgrade directly from one LTS to the next (i.e. go direct from lucid to precise). Is that right, or would I have to go through all the intermediate versions?

To add some extra details, running "lsb_release -a" gives:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid

In /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades I have Prompt=lts

Running do-release-upgrade gives the output:
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

Carlos.

Comment: Upgrading from an old unsupported version of Ubuntu to a current version is explained at : [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) m

Answer (score 1):

In shell, this is just a simple `apt-get` command.  First update the lists and upgrade any packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then upgrade your distribution:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(Might take a while!)

If that doesn't work you need to use [update manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades):

```
sudo aptitude install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Can you confirm you're on Lucid:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Should report four lines with `10.04` and `lucid` in there.  Next thing is you need upgrade manager to move to the next LTS, not 10.10 which you mention above... `vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

```
Prompt=lts
```

Try and run `do-release-upgrade again`, if you could paste out the actual fail message (in your Q) it'd be helpful too.

Comment: I tried this, and get the result: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Rudu. Using update manager at least gives a different error message, now it says: Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading            
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.   I know there is no network problem, so does this give ny clue as to what the real problem is?

Comment: No, it's maddening. Everything looks perfect, but the GUI upgrader only offers me an upgrade to 10.10, while do-release-upgrade gives "Failed upgrade tool signature, failled upgrade tool".

Comment: @CarlosPerez did you confirm you're on lucid with `lsb_release`?  The only reason I can think this is failing is you're **not** on 10.04 but actually on 10.10 which doesn't support upgrade to 12.04

Comment: Yes, "lsb_release -a" reports "Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS", "Release: 10.04", "Codename: lucid". So unless it is lying to me, I definitely seem to be running lucid!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I came upon this thread while trying to do an upgrade from Lucid to Precise and I was getting the same error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Failed Upgrade tool
Done downloading
Failed to fetch Fetching the upgrade failed.
There may be a network problem.
```

I found the issue in my `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file
I had to comment out this statement:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper";
```

Once commented out, running do_release_update worked for me.