# Integrity Check after an update fail in Xubuntu

Tags: updates, xubuntu

I have done an update (61mb ~ total) in Xubuntu 12.04 this morning but the progress bar was blocked at the start so i decided to cancel the update's installation. During the second update check the update manager that there were only 10mb ~ of updates and an error that said to run the following command: `sudo apt-get install -f`.
This command showed another error that said to run this command: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. After this command and a system reboot i think i have installed all the update but im not sure of the integrity of the system. Is there any method to see if all in my os is fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fact that you can already boot is a good sign. I went once through a botched LTS upgrade and the system wouldn't boot; I clearly stumbled onto an update bug, but managed to find a workaround and in the end it worked.

In your place I would (to make sure that all packages are up-to-date):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I would check which distribution the system is running (see [upgrade from lucid to precise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380789/upgrade-from-lucid-to-precise)):

```
lsb_release -a
```

If all checks out, and the system boots, I wouldn't worry too much about it.